# jQuery edit links with id

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, parsing, hyperlink

For my website I want to log any links that is in user created data. So I have added an id to the links e.g.

```
<a href = "http://www.somewebsite.com" id = "user_created_link">Click Here</a>
```

How would I use jQuery/javascript to edit the link that has the id `user_created_link` to:

```
<a href = "run_link.php?url=http://www.somewebsite.com" id = "user_created_link">Click Here</a>
```

I'm not looking for a direct code, I'm looking for a function? Or a hint. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDs are only supposed to be used on one element per page. But either way, you're going to want to select the elements and edit their `href` attributes, like so (making sure to escape the original URL!):

```
// assuming you use classes instead of ids...
$('.user_created_link').each(function (i, elem) {
    elem.href = 'run_link.php?url=' + encodeURIComponent(elem.href);
});
```

Comment: You'll need to encode the URL using [`eUC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent). Good point about the class name, though.

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery's [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop) + [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

```
$('#user_created_link').prop('href', function (i, orig)
{
    return 'run_link.php?url=' + encodeURIComponent(orig);
});
```

Comment: Matt, you need to change your function call slightly. You are currently encoding the index of the item. e.g. `function (i, orig)` see http://jsfiddle.net/BPAHN/ vs http://jsfiddle.net/BPAHN/1/ also if you use an ID you will only get one match http://jsfiddle.net/BPAHN/2/

Comment: Quite right, thanks! As for the second point, that's only to match the OP's markup, and @sdleihssirhc's answer addresses the uniqueness issue.